# What's the best way to cook JD biscuit rollups?

Tags: frozen, biscuits

What's the best way to cook [these](https://www.jimmydean.com/products/biscuit-rollups/sausage-egg-and-cheese/) Jimmy Dean's biscuit roll-ups?

The microwave directions aren't bad, but, as often happens with things cooked in the microwave, the biscuit is a little on the mushy side. The [toaster] oven directions (which can only be found on the website) take a long time (>20 minutes) and leave the biscuit a bit on the dry side.

If I had to pick one, I'd stick with the microwave — for a *biscuit*, I'd rather have mushy than dry — but... is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better way!

The problem is we want attributes of both cooking methods; particularly, we want the biscuit to be moist yet with a crispy crust.

The solution, then, is to combine methods!

I found that two rolls can be prepared quite nicely with the following procedure:

- Microwave on high (1100 watt microwave) for 45 seconds, slightly less than the minimum time if using *just* the microwave.
- Finish in a toaster oven on 'toast' mode on a light-to-medium setting. (I used "shade 3" on my [Cuisinart Chef](https://www.cuisinart.com/shopping/appliances/toaster_ovens/tob-260n1) and placed them in a foil-lined baking pan. The foil is optional, but saves having to wash the baking pan.)
- Remove and let stand for 1 minute (per both directions).

This produced an exterior that was delightfully golden brown and crisp, but did not dry out the biscuit nearly as much as using the toaster oven by itself.

This *does* require both a toaster oven *and* a microwave, but IMHO if you have both, the results are worth it.

It should be possible to prepare a single roll using this technique by reducing the time in the microwave. (I'm not sure if I'd go all the way down to 25 seconds, which would be the same 5 seconds less than the minimum time in the directions, or just use the minimum time of 30 seconds. Personally, I think one roll is barely worth eating. If anyone experiments, let me know!)